# Problem in mail web part

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, data-view-web-part

I wrote this code to send mail but there are exceptions in running it.

```
 public string SendEmail(string mail, string password, string to, string subject, string body, string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage Message = new MailMessage(mail, to, subject, body);
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("SMTP.Gmail.com", 587);//Gmail
                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(mail, password);
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = cred;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(Message);
                if (filePath != null)
                {
                    Attachment att = new Attachment(filePath);
                    Message.Attachments.Add(att);
                }

                return "Sucess";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error : " + ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might would like to add what exception you getting.

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.